# Key value pairs using JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Is there a way to handle data structures using JSON object in a way of Key/ Value pairs?
If so can some one elaborate how to access associated value object from the key

Assume that I have something like this

```
KEY1 |  VALUE OBJECT1 - (NAME: "XXXXXX", VALUE:100.0)  
KEY2 |  VALUE OBJECT2 - (NAME: "YYYYYYY", VALUE:200.0)  
KEY3 |  VALUE OBJECT3 - (NAME: "ZZZZZZZ", VALUE:500.0)
```

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0cgOti7gLus

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A "JSON object" is actually an oxymoron. JSON is a text format describing an object, not an actual object, so data can either be in the form of JSON, or deserialised into an object.

The JSON for that would look like this:

```
{"KEY1":{"NAME":"XXXXXX","VALUE":100},"KEY2":{"NAME":"YYYYYYY","VALUE":200},"KEY3":{"NAME":"ZZZZZZZ","VALUE":500}}
```

Once you have parsed the JSON into a Javascript object (called `data` in the code below), you can for example access the object for `KEY2` and it's properties like this:

```
var obj = data.KEY2;
alert(obj.NAME);
alert(obj.VALUE);
```

If you have the key as a string, you can use index notation:

```
var key = 'KEY3';
var obj = data[key];
```

Comment: JSON is an acronym.  Calling an instance a "JSON object" makes for a pretty clear and succinct reference. It's certainly not an "oxymoron" by any accepted definition of "oxymoron".  That JavaScript objects and JSON are not the same thing is clear: JavaScript Object Notation is a "notation" not a JavaScript object.  Is it a JSON "object"? Sure it is.

Comment: I agree with @RickO'Shea. See JSON Objects described [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp)

Answer (score 10):

```
var object = {
    key1 : {
        name : 'xxxxxx',
        value : '100.0'
    },
    key2 : {
        name : 'yyyyyyy',
        value : '200.0'
    },
    key3 : {
        name : 'zzzzzz',
        value : '500.0'
    },
}
```

If thats how your object looks and you want to loop each name and value then I would try and do something like.

```
$.each(object,function(key,innerjson){
    /*
        key would be key1,key2,key3
        innerjson would be the name and value **
    */

    //Alerts and logging of the variable.
    console.log(innerjson); //should show you the value    
    alert(innerjson.name); //Should say xxxxxx,yyyyyy,zzzzzzz
});
```

Answer (score 9):

**JSON** (= **J**ava**S**cript **O**bject **N**otation), is a lightweight and fast mechanism to convert Javascript objects into a string and vice versa.

Since Javascripts objects consists of `key/value` pairs its very easy to use and access JSON that way.

So if we have an object:

```
var myObj = {
    foo:   'bar',
    base:  'ball',
    deep:  {
       java:  'script'
    }
};
```

We can convert that into a string by calling `window.JSON.stringify(myObj);` with the result of `"{"foo":"bar","base":"ball","deep":{"java":"script"}}"`.

The other way around, we would call `window.JSON.parse("a json string like the above");`.

`JSON.parse()` returns a javascript object/array on success.

```
alert(myObj.deep.java);  // 'script'
```

`window.JSON` is not natively available in all browser. Some "older" browser need a little javascript plugin which offers the above mentioned functionality. Check http://www.json.org for further information.

Comment: Great post, although using the jQuery built in parser would be better as the OP is already using jQuery :)

Comment: @RobertPitt: The jQuery `.parseJSON()` method only does some regex checking before it trys to call `window.JSON.parse` itself. Unfortunatly, there is no `to_json` jQuery method so you would still have to fool around with `window.JSON.stringify`.

Answer (score 5):

I see what you are trying to ask and I think this is the simplest answer to what you are looking for, given you might not know how many key pairs your are being sent.

**Simple Key Pair JSON structure**

```
var data = {
    'XXXXXX' : '100.0',
    'YYYYYYY' : '200.0',
    'ZZZZZZZ' : '500.0',
}
```

**Usage JavaScript code to access the key pairs**

```
for (var key in data) 
  { if (!data.hasOwnProperty(key))
    { continue; } 
    console.log(key + ' -> ' +  data[key]);
  };
```

**Console output should look like this**

```
XXXXXX -> 100.0 
YYYYYYY -> 200.0 
ZZZZZZZ -> 500.0
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ckoakrrx/3/) to show how it works.