# How to decode array JSON objects without index quotation

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, decode

I have array JSON objects like this:

```
 $json = [
           {name: "XCB808tvXNpqXKqekA2HlkJ8H.jpg", size: 5112},
           {name: "s6kA6B0e5m1sdSAjPXqNwtiy4.jpg", size: 13135}
         ]
```

Because of some reason I don't add double quotation to `name` and `size` index and I want to decode JSON in Laravel 5.1 and iterate with `foreach()`. But when use foreach like this:

```
$json = json_decode($json,true);
         foreach ($json as $val) {
            Image::create(['filename' => $val['name'], 'size' => $val['size']]);
         }
```

and error me:

```
json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

Comment: Where is from your JSON data?

Comment: javascript (angularjs)

Comment: And why this wrong format? It is from your own code? If it is, can you show js code?. This because yes, it possible fix your issue in php, but if you have a valid JSON is much much much better

Comment: "I have array JSON objects like this: — That isn't JSON. It looks like valid Javascript … but you then seem to be trying to use the variable in PHP. I isn't valid PHP.

Answer (score 1):

`json_decode()` is used to decode a json string to an array/data object.

`json_encode()` creates a json string from an array or data.

**UPDATE:**

error message clearly told that `You are passing an array to json_decode, but it expects a string.` It looks like you have to iterate over array: So do it.

```
foreach($arr as $i => $json) {
    $arr[$i] = json_decode($json, true);
}
```

Use this JSON. Hope it will work.

```
[
  {
    "name": "XCB808tvXNpqXKqekA2HlkJ8H.jpg",
    "size": "5112"
  },
  {
    "name": "s6kA6B0e5m1sdSAjPXqNwtiy4.jpg",
    "size": "13135"
  }
]
```

**Follow the link:**

1. http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php
2. [Key value pairs using JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715644/key-value-pairs-using-json)
3. http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp

Comment: I want to decode `$json`. I fetch `$json` from ajax request (javascript).

Comment: Question title: “ How to decode array JSON objects without index quotation”