# Get all keys and values from JSON data

Tags: json

I have the following json data:

```
{
  "version": "2017-07-05",
  "clientid": "s0001",
  "statement": {
    "publisher": "raspberry pi",
    "publishstatus": false,
    "subscribestatus": false,
    "subscribedetails": {
      "topic": "None",
      "assetdetails": {
        "assetname": "None",
        "assetid": "None"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I get all the keys and its respective values in python?
For example:

```
"version": "2017-07-05",
"clientid": "s0001",
"publishstatus": false,
"topic": "None",
"assetname": "None",
```

Comment: you need json or you need logic?

Comment: In which language?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take some time to read [How to ask good questions?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also please try to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your own attempt and show it to us.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Key value pairs using JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715644/key-value-pairs-using-json)

Comment: @NegiRox, I actually needed the login and also code in python. One of my friends has done it using recursion. Thank you by the way.